# Extraneous signal is raised while executing a signal action

Tags: c

when the process executes a signal action, and an another signal occurs,what will happen?
I have written a test program to check it. Will it run on the linux?

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <signal.h>  

static void sighandle(int signo){  
    printf("sig %d start\n",signo);  
    sleep(10);  
    printf("sig %d end\n",signo);  
}  

int main(void){  
    if(signal(SIGUSR1,sighandle)){  
            perror("signal");  
            return -1;  
    }  
    if(signal(SIGUSR2,sighandle)){  
            perror("signal");  
            return -1;  
    }  
    while(1){  
            pause();  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

I have executed it like:

```
root@virtual-machine:~# ./a.out &

[1] 10140

kill -SIGUSR1 10140      root@gmdz-virtual-machine:~# sig 10 start

kill -SIGUSR2 10140  
    sig 12 start

root@gmdz-virtual-machine:~# sig 12 end 

sig 10 end
```

My question is:

1. When sigusr1 action was running, the sigusr2 came, so the two sig actions were running at the same time,like two thread,is it right?
2. If the 1 is right,why the sigusr1 can not finish running unitl the sigusr2 finish? if the 1 is wrong, can you explain the reason?
   thank you.

Comment: An interrupt interrupts! It is not executed in parallel like a thread.

Answer (score 0):

when a process in sleeping stat,The process also can process signal,it in one thread.

so 1 is wrong.

when the process turn to running stat from sleeping,it processing the SIGUSR2 again.